# Is Flare visualization library still being developed/supported right now?

Tags: actionscript-3, flare, graph-visualization

I just found out about [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) actionscript library and was thinking of using it for a couple or projects.
However I was wondering whether it's still supported at some level; I just checked the [forums](http://goosebumps4all.net/34all/bb/forumdisplay.php?fid=28) but all messages seem to be a bit old already...

Does anyone have any information about this?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Pablo

Comment: Looks like the project migrated hosting over to Github a while ago, and the last commit shows at Apr 2011. Issues posted there haven't been answered, so I'd guess development has stalled / is on hiatus / abandoned. For the actual answer to this question,  I'd suggest you ask them yourself via Github.

Comment: @Slomojo thanks for the info, I'll ask them on Github and will let you know what they tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I got from them:

> Flare [Visualization Toolkit] AS3 is not actively supported. In first
>   quarter of 2012, however, I will be porting Flare to use Flex Mobile
>   and Starling for high-speed robust renderings on mobile devices.